# PHP Cannot Write to Socket?

Tags: php, sockets

For some reason whenever I try writing to a socket, I get this error:

```
Notice: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: send of 7 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted in /home/www/MySiteName/someFile.php on line 165
```

Is there something I am missing in my php.ini file? I am currently running PHP v5.2.6

Since code was asked for:

```
$this->Socket = @FSockOpen( 'udp://' . $Ip, (int)$Port, $ErrNo, $ErrStr, $Timeout );
FWrite( $this->Socket, $Command, $Length )
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: This says nothing. Show the code that creates the socket

Comment: Anything else you need?

Comment: Are you sure that the host is available and the remote port is open?

Comment: My first thought would be to check the firewall settings for the port and to ensure that you have permission to write to sockets. Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: I am connecting fine, I just cannot write to it. @djiheru where would I check if I have permission to write to sockets? I am on shared hosting (hopefully only for another month).

Comment: Remove the `@` operator

Comment: @Ultimate There is no connection in UDP. As the PHP manual states, the error can happen even if `fsockopen()` returns success.

Comment: Does this help?
http://tst.burngames.net/ping.php

Comment: Lets take this back a 'notch' (yes I checked out and registered on your site), Can you read from the socket? I can post some old socket code that I had working a while back if I can find it too

Comment: First off, this is quite old. Second, I figured it out. My host disabled it for "security reasons". I contacted them, and they enabled it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host disabled it for "security reasons". I contacted them, and they enabled it again.